# Unable to decode json data

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make call to an url using requests module but for some reasons, I am getting this error - `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Here is my code:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={'Accept':'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}).json()
return response['data']
```

Please what am I missing here?

Comment: requests.post(url, data=data, headers={'Accept':'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}) what does this return? would seem like youre getting an empty  response

Comment: The .json() is throwing that error because it can't convert the response object to a json object. Most probably your url/server is returning an error response which can't not be converted into a json object.